# can't predict value with my tensorflow js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

please someone help me out and put me through. am new to tensorflow js. what i want to understand is after training a dataset let say we have [{x1, y1},{x2, y2},{x3, y3}]. so i assume we only need to provide x to get y prediction. but i didn't understand from extactly after training dataset. please check my code below

```
/**
 * Get the car data reduced to just the variables we are interested
 * and cleaned of missing data.
 */
async function getData() {
  const carsDataResponse = await fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-tutorials/carsData.json');  
  const carsData = await carsDataResponse.json();  
  
  const cleaned = carsData.map(car => ({
    mpg: car.Miles_per_Gallon,
    horsepower: car.Horsepower,
  }))
  .filter(car => (car.mpg != null && car.horsepower != null));
  //console.log(cleaned)
  return cleaned;
}

//console.log(y_data)
function createModel() {
  // Create a sequential model
  const model = tf.sequential(); 
  
  // Add a single input layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [1], units: 1, useBias: true}));
  
  // Add an output layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, useBias: true}));

  return model;
}

// Create the model
const model = createModel();  
tfvis.show.modelSummary({name: 'Model Summary'}, model);


/**
 * Convert the input data to tensors that we can use for machine 
 * learning. We will also do the important best practices of _shuffling_
 * the data and _normalizing_ the data
 * MPG on the y-axis.
 */
function convertToTensor(data) {
  // Wrapping these calculations in a tidy will dispose any 
  // intermediate tensors.
  
  return tf.tidy(() => {
    // Step 1. Shuffle the data    
    tf.util.shuffle(data);

    // Step 2. Convert data to Tensor
    const inputs = data.map(d => d.horsepower)
    const labels = data.map(d => d.mpg);

    const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
    const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);

    //Step 3. Normalize the data to the range 0 - 1 using min-max scaling
    const inputMax = inputTensor.max();
    const inputMin = inputTensor.min();  
    const labelMax = labelTensor.max();
    const labelMin = labelTensor.min();

    const normalizedInputs = inputTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));
    const normalizedLabels = labelTensor.sub(labelMin).div(labelMax.sub(labelMin));

    return {
      inputs: normalizedInputs,
      labels: normalizedLabels,
      // Return the min/max bounds so we can use them later.
      inputMax,
      inputMin,
      labelMax,
      labelMin,
    }
  });  
}



async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
  // Prepare the model for training.  
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
    metrics: ['mse'],
  });
  
  const batchSize = 32;
  const epochs = 50;
  
  return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
    batchSize,
    epochs,
    shuffle: true,
    callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
      { name: 'Training Performance' },
      ['loss', 'mse'], 
      { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
    )
  });
}


function testModel(model, inputData, normalizationData) {
  const {inputMax, inputMin, labelMin, labelMax} = normalizationData;  
  
  // Generate predictions for a uniform range of numbers between 0 and 1;
  // We un-normalize the data by doing the inverse of the min-max scaling 
  // that we did earlier.
  const [xs, preds] = tf.tidy(() => {
    
    const xs = tf.linspace(0, 1, 100);      
    const preds = model.predict(xs.reshape([100, 1]));      
    //console.log(xs);
    const unNormXs = xs
      .mul(inputMax.sub(inputMin))
      .add(inputMin);
    
    const unNormPreds = preds
      .mul(labelMax.sub(labelMin))
      .add(labelMin);
    
    // Un-normalize the data
    return [unNormXs.dataSync(), unNormPreds.dataSync()];
  });
  
 
  const predictedPoints = Array.from(xs).map((val, i) => {
    return {x: val, y: preds[i]}
  });
  
  const originalPoints = inputData.map(d => ({
    x: d.horsepower, y: d.mpg,
  }));
  console.log(originalPoints);
  
  tfvis.render.scatterplot(
    {name: 'Model Predictions vs Original Data'}, 
    {values: [originalPoints, predictedPoints], series: ['original', 'predicted']}, 
    {
      xLabel: 'Horsepower',
      yLabel: 'MPG',
      height: 300
    }
  );
}
```

/////////////this is where i try to give one value to predict the other//////////////////////

```
async function run() {
  // Load and plot the original input data that we are going to train on.
  const data = await getData();
  const values = data.map(d => ({
    x: d.horsepower,
    y: d.mpg,
  }));

  tfvis.render.scatterplot(
    {name: 'Horsepower v MPG'},
    {values}, 
    {
      xLabel: 'Horsepower',
      yLabel: 'MPG',
      height: 300
    }
  );

  // More code will be added below
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
    var y_data;
    getData().then(data=>{
     const y_data = data;
     console.log(y_data);
     const Ty_data = convertToTensor(y_data);

    trainModel(model, Ty_data.inputs, Ty_data.labels);

    //here am trying to predict mpg by providing horsepower
    var xs_val = [horsepower: 800];

    const x_xs = convertToTensor(xs_val);
    console.log(x_xs);
    testModel(model, x_xs.inputs, x_xs);
     

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unpack an array in Javascript like this.

`const {inputMax, inputMin, labelMin, labelMax} = normalizationData;`

Also, please provide the error you are getting; there is very little information to go off of here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, am not really getting error but there's something I want to understand, which is how to predict, for example in a case where we have series of price with date. So how will I predict price of a date in future

Comment: Look at this.                                                              const xs = tf.linspace(0, 1, 100);      
    const preds = model.predict(xs.reshape([100, 1]));      
    So literally what I want to understand is.               Predict (passing date of price u want predict)

Comment: If you are wanting to know how to predict with just X, you're doing it in the code with `model.predict`. If you're talking about with the input data, it looks like you need to use `model.predict(inputData)`, or some rearrangement of it. inputData probably has to be normalized first. It's incredibly unclear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Can you please let have a Google meet or zoom @Andy K